# docker container hanging on run - how to debug

Tags: docker, dockerfile, google-cloud-run

I am trying to run Screaming Frog in a docker.  For this I have used as a starting point, this Github project:

https://github.com/iihnordic/screamingfrog-docker

After building, I ran the docker with the follwing command:

```
docker run -v /<my-path>/screamingfrog-crawls:/home/crawls screamingfrog --crawl https://<my-domain> --headless --save-crawl 
--output-folder /home/crawls
```

It worked the first time, but after multiple attempts, it seems that the process hangs 8 out of 10 times with no error, always hanging at a different stage in the process.

I assumed the most likely reason is memory, but despite significantly increasing the docker memory and also increasing the Screaming Frog Memory to 16GB the same issue persists.

How can I go about debugging my container when no errors are thrown except for the container hanging indefinitely

As suggested by @Ralle, I checked docker stats, and while it seems that Memory usage is actually staying well below 10%, the CPU is always of 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

docker stats:
returns something like this.
At least you can see the behaviour of memory and cpu.

```
CONTAINER ID   NAME         CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O           BLOCK I/O         PIDS
3.18kB / 496B     17.2MB / 41.4MB   8
9949a4ee1238   nest-api-1   0.87%     290MiB / 3.725GiB     7.60%     2.14MB / 37.2kB   156kB / 2.06MB    33
96fe43dba2b0   postgres     0.00%     29MiB / 3.725GiB      0.76%     7.46kB / 6.03kB   1.17MB / 67.8MB   7
ff570659e917   redis        0.30%     3.004MiB / 3.725GiB   0.08%     2.99kB / 0B       614kB / 4.1kB     5
```

ALSO docker top  shows you you the pid ids.

I dont know your application, but check also what if the issue can be related to the volumes itselfs each time the container restarts.